# “Standardizing variables” in the procedure of converting First Order Logic to CNF?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, conjunctive-normal-form

In below question of converting the given formula into clause normal form, I stuck in the step “Standardizing variables”.Can someone explain to me whether my steps are correct and how to do “Standardizing variables” part in below formula? Also the other steps until obtaining clause normal form?

Here, q, p are predicate symbols. The square brackets were used to improve readability.They have the same meaning as round brackets.

∀x:([¬∃y:q(x,y)]∧[∃x∀y:(p(x,y)→p(y,y))])

step 1: remove →

∀x:([¬∃y:q(x,y)]∧[¬∃x∀y:(p(x,y)∨p(y,y))])

step 2: move ¬ inwards

∀x:([¬∃y:q(x,y)]∧[∀x∃y:(¬p(x,y)∧¬p(y,y))])

step 3: Standardizing variables

I stuck in here. Can someone explain me from this step? It would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simply replacing variables with other variables so that you never have two quantifiers in the same sentence quantifying the same variable.

IN your sentence you have two quantifiers that quantify a $x$ and two quantifiers that quantify a $y$, so you want to replace one of the $x$ variables with a different variable, for example a $v$, and one of the $y$ variables with a different variable yet, say a $w$.

Notice that you can do this as your very first step, and personally that is what I typically do, since having unique variables play unique roles in the sentences prevents getting confused about which variable is quantifed by which quantifier.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do I have to replace both x and y ? Could you please give me some further steps?

Comment: ∀x:([¬∃z:q(x,z)]∧[∀u∃y:(¬p(u,y)∧¬p(y,y))]) is this is correct? So that means it doesn't matter which variable I am replacing?

Comment: @user2397555 Yes, both the second $x$ and the second $y$. SO, I would immediately change the original sentence into $\forall x ([\neg \exists y \: q(x,y)] \land [\exists v \forall w (p(v,w) \rightarrow p(w,w))])$

Comment: @user2397555 yes, that works as well!  It indeed does not matter. IN fact, you can a,lways just replace *all* variables and use $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, etc. ESpecially when you have many variables, that's what I do.

Comment: @user2397555 Glad I could help! :)

Comment: One more question. ∀x∀u∃y∀z:([q(x,z)]∧[(¬p(u,y)∧¬p(y,y))]) so this is in clause normal form right?

Comment: @user2397555 Yes, that is in CNF ... it's not what you should get from your posted sentence though ... your first step is not quite right. YOu should replace the $\rightarrow$ *inside* the quantifiers .. so you get $\neg p(x,y) \lor p(y,y)$

Comment: @user2397555 Also, the first term $q$ term should end up with a $\neg$ in front of it.